# how to assign image dynamically in wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing one wordpress site. I have made one post in it. Now I want to assign image in that post. For this, I have uploaded one image in media and attach that image to my post.

but how can I assign that uploaded image in my post? do I need to give path manually? or I can give dynamic path so that even if I upload this site on server or change main folder name, path gets changed automatically..

any help will be appreciated.. 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [Post Thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) (also known as Featured Images) in your posts. To do this, all you need to do is add the following to your functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

This will add a control in your Post Editor to add an image by either Uploading it or setting the URL, effectively "attaching" your image to your post in the way your looking for. To display the image in your template:

```
<?php
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    if(has_post_thumbnail())
        echo '<div class="post_thumb">'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'</div>';
?>
<div class="post_content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

As for changing folder names, paths, etc. you need to be careful with that approach. Remember that you're giving a path to an asset. The server doesn't know what YOU want, only what your code is requesting. If you expect to be changing paths to your assets around quite a bit, then you can always forgo Post Thumbnails in favor of clever naming conventions. Something like this:

```
<?php
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
$imgPath = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/featured_'.$post->post_name.'.jpg';
?>
<div class="post_thumb"><img src="<?php echo $imgPath; ?>" /></div>
<div class="post_content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

This looks for an image in your Theme Directory's images folder that is named featured_{post_slug}.jpg

The benefits to this approach is that Wordpress will always know where your theme folder is, regardless of URL changes. As long as you have an images folder in your theme directory, Wordpress will know where to look.

The drawback is that this code specifically doesn't first check for the EXISTENCE of the image before displaying it, which could lead to broken images if they aren't named properly or don't exist at all. This approach also requires the use of one file extension

A last option for you is to consider using [Custom Fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) to define paths to images. The benefit is that this does not require you to actually upload images to your server. However, this approach is still the least dynamic out of all of your options, and will likely break if paths to assets are changed.

Use whichever tool you feel is best for the job. Hope this helps!